# How do I integrate Electron and CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, electron

Within an application created with the Electron framework, how would one execute a CasperJS script?

The functionality would look like:

1. Button is clicked
2. JavaScript function is called
3. myCasperTest.js is executed

It would be ideal if any console output from myCasperTest could be returned to the application.

Comment: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare

Comment: Please note that CasperJS is not a node.js module. It's only installed through npm for convenience. The same is true for PhantomJS, which is a standalone executable.

Comment: @DanielLizik that is a great library. thanks for referencing it